# Split string at every Nth occurrence of character

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split a string like the following after every fourth pipe -

Input -

> `userid456|userid457|userid458|userid459|userid460|userid461|userid462|userid463|userid464|userid465|userid466|userid467|userid468|userid469|userid470|userid471|userid472|userid473|userid474|userid475|userid476|userid477|userid478|userid479|userid480|userid481|userid482|userid483`

Output -

```
userid456|userid457|userid458|userid459

userid460|userid461|userid462|userid463

userid464|userid465|userid466|userid467

userid468|userid469|userid470|userid471
```

etc.

Was trying to figure out if there is an easy way using regexp and String.split()

Comment: Another method may be to split on *every* pipe and then re-build the output string. And another is to run a character search n-times (supplying the last found index + 1 as the starting location) and replace the character at the nth location.

Comment: Thanks. But, was trying to find out if there was a single regex approach.

Comment: `indexOf('|', 7)` + `substring`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `split` you can use a match using this regex:

```
(?:[^|]+\|){3}[^|]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9oQMw/2)

**Java Code:**

```
final String regex = "(?:[^|]*\\|){3}[^|]*";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: It is just matter of using `*` instead of `+` in above regex

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off matching instead of splitting.
It's the same effect, but with more control.

`((?:[^|]*?\|){3}[^|]*?)\||([\S\s]+)`

Explained

```
     (                             # (1 start)
          (?:                           # Group - 3 pipes
               [^|]*?                        # Optional non-pipe chars
               \|                            # Pipe
          ){3}                          # End group 
          [^|]*?                        # Optional non-pipe chars
     )                             # (1 end)
     \|                            # 4th pipe, consume but do not capture

  |  
     ( [\S\s]+ )                   # (2), Final text less than 4 pipes
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come up with is this:

```
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\G(\\w{1,11}\\|){4}+)");
```

This has two issues:

1. you must specify a max number of characters between the **|** chars
2. It will include the **|** at the end of each part

The output looks like:

```
userid456|userid457|userid458|userid459|
userid460|userid461|userid462|userid463|
userid464|userid465|userid466|userid467|
userid468|userid469|userid470|userid471|
userid472|userid473|userid474|userid475|
userid476|userid477|userid478|userid479|
userid480|userid481|userid482|userid483
```